# Can a single-spa application also be a progressive web app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, single-spa

We are looking at using single-spa.js for micro frontends.  One question that has been asked is if a single-spa app can also be a progressive web app (PWA). Searching hasn't revealed much information on the matter. The individual apps will be react-apps if that's important. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're not finding much is because there is no difference between the single-spa architecture and every other website when it comes to Progressive Web Apps (which refers to several sets of browser APIs). With single-spa, you can use any browser APIs that you wish. Typically the service worker is setup in the root config. There's only one specific thing I'd call out: per the browser spec, you can only have one service worker per web page, which means it can’t be one service worker per microfrontend (only one big shared one).

Answer (score 0):

There's only one specific thing I'd call out: per the browser spec, you can only have one service worker per web page, which means it can’t be one service worker per microfrontend (only one big shared one).

What makes you say that? by one service worker per web page...that could refer to any page served on a route [www.site.com/route](http://www.site.com/route). Do you mean you can only use a pwa within one domain / dns for a website? If so, where have you found this evidence?

Why would this example not also work for an app using single-spa? https://web.dev/articles/building-multiple-pwas-on-the-same-domain

I cannot tell you it is possible but also I do not think we have the information needed to say we cannot.

Answer (score 0):

In SPA, when you request [example.com/some/path](http://example.com) , server  serves same files as if it is serving [example.com/](http://example.com) . But spa framework figures out which page to show and prepare that page to requester.

In that sense spa is already pwa. But when you build spa, bundle has every page, so gets huge. (Because of that nextjs, spliting bundles to paths).

I think its better to think on structure of your app,

- Admins, editors, viewers etc should not be accessing same tools.
- Complexity of places (categories, landing pages)
- common elements

  (lists, hero sections, etc)

And choose what ever you feel nice and common.